# is the model regenerated at every invokation of nn.Sequential?

Tags: pytorch

I am dealing with pytorch, I would like to know wheter if nn.Sequential is called more than once it means the model gets regenerated.

Waiting for your answer,
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by *"model gets regenerated"*?

Answer (score 0):

nn.Sequential is not a function, it's a class.

When you "call" nn.Sequential you create an instance of this class. You can now use the model to do whatever you want. If you create another instance ("call" it again) it will simply create another unrelated model